# How to manually create a boost ptree with different XML attributes?

Tags: c++, xml, boost, xml-parsing, boost-propertytree

I am using boost libraries to parse XML files and I have to create a ptree manually.
I want to create below xml file using boost ptree.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Txn>
    <Resp errCode="0" errInfo="" />
    <A exptime="20171230">xyz Information</A>
    <B>xyz Information</B>
    <C type="Active">xyz Information</C>
</Txn>
```

To achieve above xml,
Below is my sample code:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptr1;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptr2;
boost::property_tree::ptree ptr3;

ptr1.put("<xmlattr>.errCode", Txn.resp.errCode);
ptr1.put("<xmlattr>.errInfo", Txn.resp.errInfo);

ptr2.push_back(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type("A", boost::property_tree::ptree(data)));
ptr2.push_back(boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type("C", boost::property_tree::ptree(data)));

ptr2.put("A.<xmlattr>.exptime", data);
ptr2.put("C.<xmlattr>.type", data);


ptr3.put("<xmlattr>", data);

pt.add_child("Txn.Resp", ptr1);
pt.add_child("Txn", ptr2);
pt.add_child("Txn.B", ptr3);
```

Here Child `A` and `C` always create as a separate with Parent `Txn` But I want to add all child in `Txn` Parent

. I did not understand, why child A and C are different here.
It would be very helpful, If someone help me to provide right way.

Comment: I have updated my question with problem point. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the simplest thing I can think of:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8ae80d2d4667a273)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/property_tree/xml_parser.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using boost::property_tree::ptree;
static auto pretty = boost::property_tree::xml_writer_make_settings<std::string>(' ', 4);

int main() {
    ptree root;
    root.add("Txn.Resp.<xmlattr>.errCode", 0);
    root.add("Txn.Resp.<xmlattr>.errInfo", "");

    root.add("Txn.A", "xyz Information");
    root.add("Txn.A.<xmlattr>.exptime", "20171230");

    root.add("Txn.B", "xyz Information");

    root.add("Txn.C", "xyz Information");
    root.add("Txn.C.<xmlattr>.type", "Active");

    write_xml(std::cout, root, pretty);
}
```

Prints:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Txn>
    <Resp errCode="0" errInfo="" />
    <A exptime="20171230">xyz Information</A>
    <B>xyz Information</B>
    <C type="Active">xyz Information</C>
</Txn>
```

Key point is to create the element node before adding attributes, otherwise you get this instead:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25b526f7a3d89bdd)</kbd>**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Txn>
    <Resp errCode="0" errInfo=""/>
    <A exptime="20171230"/>
    <A>xyz Information</A>
    <B>xyz Information</B>
    <C type="Active"/>
    <C>xyz Information</C>
</Txn>
```